# getting sequence number from mongodb always undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, seq

I am trying to get by code the next sequence number but it always says "undefined".

I did this in my mongoDB before:

```
db.PresentationCollection.insert(
   {
      _id: "editorID",
      seq: 0
   }
)
```

my code (name is editorID):

```
function getNextSequence(name, db) {

    var collection = db.get('PresentationCollection');

    var ret = collection.findAndModify(
           {
               query: { _id: name },
               update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
               new: true
           }
    );

    return ret.seq;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the callback. Callback-based asynchronous functions generally do not return anything meaningful. See the documentation for [findAndModify](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#find-and-modify) in the node binding's readme.

Comment: not working for me, i think i mistake with the syntax, can you write here something that works ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem from following this link and it is indeed the callback not being specified and your code not waiting for the returned result - [mongo db documents create auto increment](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)

Here is what I did to solve it. Keep in mind I am using Q for promise helping but you could use straight up javascript promises.

```
function _getNextSequence(name) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  db.counters.findAndModify(
    { _id: name }, //query
    [], //sort
    { $inc: { seq: 1 } }, //update
    { new:true }, //options
    function(err, doc) { //callback
      if (err) deferred.reject(err.name + ': ' + err.message);
      if (doc){
        deferred.resolve(doc.value.seq);
      }
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```